# Is “Light of moon and ray of star” an idiom?

Tags: idioms, literary-techniques, literary-english, literary-device

What is the literary device used for the following quote from [The Fellowship of the Ring](http://tolkien.cro.net/talesong/s-berenl.html) :

> By light of moon and ray of star

I think that it is an idiom.... I may be wrong!

Comment: I guess that's from [Tolkien](http://tolkien.cro.net/talesong/s-berenl.html), is it? Or did you have another author in mind? (It's always best to quote the source in the question)

Comment: It's not an "idiom" in the sense of "established usage that apparently contravenes normal syntax". It's just a one-off "poetic-archaic" usage by Tolkien that would probably *never* occur again except as an intentional reference to the "original".

Comment: Not even Tolkien seems to have managed to get it so widely used as to qualify as an _idiom_. It's certainly in the poetic register. 'By the light of the silvery moon' would seem to be a fixed expression (popularised by the film and song), but 'by ray of star' is very idiosyncratic.

Comment: @andrew-leach I added your link into the question body

Answer (score 3):

## *Eye of newt and toe of frog*

If idioms by their words invoke
some special meaning hard to guess,
then no, this turn of phrase you’ll note
has none of that: it’s for the stress.

Instead it turns the word around
to better fit its count and line
and measure beats out as they sound,
this more for meter than for rhyme:

- by right of birth (by birthright)
- by force of arms (by armed force)
- by force of will (by willpower)
- by dark of night (by darkness)
- by light of day (by daylight)
- by light of sun (by sunlight)
- by break of day (by daybreak)

---

#### Tolkien

> *He sought her ever, wandering far
>
>   Where **leaves of years** were thickly strewn,
>
>   By **light of moon** and **ray of star**
>
>   In frosty heavens shivering.*

> *A king he was on carven throne
>
>   In many-pillared halls of stone
>
>   With golden roof and silver floor,
>
>   And runes of power upon the door.
>
>   The **light of sun and star and moon**
>
>   In shining lamps of crystal hewn
>
>   Undimmed **by cloud or shade of night**
>
>   There shone for ever fair and bright.*

---

#### Shakespeare

> *Fillet of a fenny snake,
>
>   In the cauldron boil and bake;
>
>   **Eye of newt**, and **toe of frog**,
>
>   **Wool of bat**, and **tongue of dog**,
>
>   Adder's fork, and blind-worm’s sting,
>
>   Lizard's leg, and howlet's wing,
>
>   For a charm of powerful trouble,
>
>   Like a hell-broth boil and bubble.*
>
> ***Scale of dragon**, **tooth of wolf**,
>
>   Witches’ mummy, maw and gulf
>
>   Of the ravin’d salt-sea shark,
>
>   **Root of hemlock** digg’d i’ the dark,
>
>   Liver of blaspheming Jew,
>
>   **Gall of goat**, and **slips of yew**
>
>   Silver’d in the moon’s eclipse,
>
>   **Nose of Turk** and Tartar’s lips,
>
>   Finger of birth-strangled babe
>
>   Ditch-deliver’d by a drab,
>
>   Make the gruel thick and slab:
>
>   Add thereto a tiger’s chaudron,
>
>   For the ingredients of our cauldron.*

Comment: Interesting short article on Tolkien's poems' rhythm at http://www.kith.org/journals/neology/2010/07/four-footed-poets.html - it discusses  how Tolkien loves using iambic tetrameter in his poems.

Comment: Also I’m intrigued to see the way that night and day; that dark of night and light of day are different. 

“Daylight” has a different form from “darkness” as we see, but how does “Daybreak” earn a place beside them?

Just as “night dark” isn’t “darkness”, “daybreak” takes a different form and then where are we?